# Default :target with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab:target {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="tab_container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#updates-list">List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#updates-map">Map</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tab list" id="updates-list">
    Eh.. Hello!
  </ul>
  <div class="tab map" id="updates-map"></div>
</div>
```

However, my page is empty if no target (`#` in URL) is specified and no tab is clicked yet. I want to show `ul#updates-list` by default.

How can I do this? Thanks.

---

Update: Next to this, my Google Map is broken if it is not the initial target. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: From the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo): "If the document's URI has no fragment identifier, then the document has no target element." Boo!

Comment: Why boo? What would you expect `:target` to match then if there is no fragment identifier? The root element? *Every element* (or every `[id], a[name]`)? Or the default among a subset of `[id], a[name]` within the document that *the author expects based on their own intentions* to ever be referenced via a fragment identifier, something that neither CSS nor even the DOM could possibly have any knowledge of?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spontaneously I'd have to say that the only solution I can think of is unfortunately using JavaScript. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (document.location.hash == "" || document.location.hash == "#")
    document.location.hash = "#updates-list";
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, got a CSS solution. This however requires the default entry `#updates-list` to be placed last (after `#updates-map` and any other tabs you may add):

```
.tab, .tab:target ~ #updates-list  {
  display: none;
}
#updates-list, .tab:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but can you explain a bit more about how your css solution selects a default target? what is .tab? he used no .tab? should be .tabs? or

Comment: `#updates-list` is the default, because that is what I'm specifying in the rule `#updates-list, .tab:target { ... }`. `.tab` is the class on the contents of the tabs not the tabs themselves - compare my CSS to the CSS in the question.

Comment: ok so the second line says display the default class in same style as :target? and the first line says style the default class the same as not target if a target is a sibling? but wont the second line override it anyway? i am trying to get it to work with this example from http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/ - http://jsfiddle.net/ArHdb/ thanks a lot

Comment: Well my solution above is based on tabs that are separate from their contents. First the tabs, then the contents. Your code has tabs and contents mixed up, so it can't apply and you'll need a completely different solution, which don't have the time to think about right now...

Comment: This example works great, except there is a [bug in iOS 4.3 that causes it not to work correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/rED4c/).

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it's still relevant and I have another suggestion:

```
<a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>

<a id="tab1"></a>
<a id="tab2"></a>

<div class="tab tab1 default-tab">Some content</div>
<div class="tab tab2">Some other content</div>
```

and the css:

```
.tab {display:none}

.default-tab {display:block}

:target ~ .default-tab {display:none}

#tab1:target ~ .tab1,
#tab2:target ~ .tab2 {
  display: block
}
```

This lets you have the tabs ordered however you want, but if you're generating the html dynamically you'll need to generate the css dynamically. Or else choose a maximum number of tabs to support when you write the css.

Comment: Finally!  This is the first thing I've found that works.  I'm using #home instead of .default-tab, but still.  Amazing.  Thank you.  The other solution I found was using :last instead, and that wasn't working at all.  It still has the issue that the default tab has to be last, but if you're only displaying one at a time, that's a non-issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the shortest answer I could find:

`location=location.hash||"#updates-list"`

This simply redirects the user to a valid hash if it is currently nonexistent  or empty `#`.

~98% of users have JavaScript enabled, so a JS solution shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you would want to do is select something like `.tab_container:not(> :target) > .default` to display the default tab when no one is targeted. However, this is not possible since the `:not()` pseudo-class only takes simple selectors (i.e. just `:target`, not `> :target`, in which case you would check the target of the container, not the children).

I would do either of the following:

- Use Javascript to set the target to the first tab at load (or just require that the anchor is present).
- Add a specific override class for the first active tab and remove it (again with Javascript) after the first tab switch.

The first alternative will mess with the browser history while the second will be a bit more of a code mess. I can't think of a "perfect" solution right now. Maybe you're better off just using Javascript altogether to detect the current target in order to both get compatibility with non-CSS3 browsers and to solve this particular issue in a somewhat clean way?

Comment: Compatibility is not a problem. I only care about Webkit.

Comment: This *might* be possible in the future with `.tab_container:not(:has(> :target)) > .default`, but only if `:has()` with a child combinator makes it into CSS. Otherwise you'll still have to use JavaScript. (FWIW, the example I've given totally works in jQuery today.)

Answer (score 0):

Useful:

```
.tab#tabControl { display:block; }

.tab:not(:target) { display:none; }

.tab:target ~ #tabControl { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure CSS solution, but it uses one tiny bit of JavaScript that vastly simplifies the all the code:

```js
location=location.hash||"#one"
```

(Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470599/1282216)

Here's minimalist SPA (Single Page Application) that demonstrates this. The first "page" is visible right away, but then hidden when the other links are clicked

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>personal web page</title>

<style>

 section:target {
  display: block;
}

section {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<h1>About me</h1>

<nav>
  <a href="#one">Travel</a>
  <a href="#two">Hobbies</a>
  <a href="#three">Links</a>
</nav>

<section id="one">  
  <h2>Travel</h2>
  <p>Places I like to travel to.</p>
</section>  

<section id="two">  
   <h2>Hobbies</h2>
   <p>Things I like to do.</p>
</section> 

<section id="three">  
  <h2>Links</h2>
  <p>My favourite links.</p>
</section>

<script>
  location=location.hash||"#one"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, different than any yet displayed here.  I believe this is limited to fairly modern browsers (I don't know the full compatibility list, but it's working for me in a Chromium from late 2023), however the following CSS worked for me, with only a minor tweak to the HTML (shown below):

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab:target, :not(:has(.tab:target)) .tab.default {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

And actually, I found another solution after posting this, that's arguably even better -- though it requires changing the `ul` that's got id `updates-list` to be a `div` (or at least wrap it in one, with a `class` attribute that contains `tab`):

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab:target {
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  &:not(:has(.tab:target)) {
    & .tab:first-of-type {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

(I'm now back to talking about the first solution.)

For the HTML, I basically just added `default` to the class list for the `#updates-list` ul tag:

(Notes: you could also still select by ID, instead of a new class, I just found this cleaner somehow - YMMV.  I also added some text to `#updates-map` for the sake of having something on the screen when I was testing out this example.)

```html
<div class="tab_container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#updates-list">List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#updates-map">Map</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tab list default" id="updates-list">
    Eh.. Hello!
  </ul>
  <div class="tab map" id="updates-map">
    [Imagine a map here.]
  </div>
</div>
```

### Explanation:

The second selector in that second section of CSS, `:not(:has(.tab:target)) .tab.default`, looks for a situation in which there is no `.tab` item that has the `:target` attribute, and then in that case, also applies `display: block;` to any `.tab` element which also has the `.default` class applied.

This also has a couple extra benefits:

1. It doesn't require any particular order, as in [RoToRa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354472/313756);
2. One could potentially have multiple tabs that had the default attribute, so multiple things would display on the page if there wasn't a specific target selected (if there was, then only that target would be displayed, as before).

As a side note, I was inspired to find this solution because of [a talk by Amy Kapernick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKU65gV6FSA) on doing things like this without JavaScript, and the second solution in this answer is adapted almost verbatim from her [nojs demo site](https://nojs.amyskapers.dev/), where she shows off these things.