# CSS selector when :target empty

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need a **css3** selector to target an element when the :target equals the id of the element (easy) or when the `:target` is empty (impossible?). It’s hard to explain, so let me give you a simple example.

```
div {
  background: blue;
}
div:target, div:no-target {
  background: red;
}
```

But of course the `:no-target` pseudo class doesn’t exist ;). Is there a way around this without using **Javascript**? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sigh.  I feel like I'm resurrecting a dead topic, but it needs a real answer.

It's possible to do this with CSS alone, just by using `:last-child` and a [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), in the form of `:target ~ :last-child`:

```
.pages > .page:target ~ .page:last-child,
.pages > .page {
    display: none;
}

/* :last-child works, but .page:last-child will not */
.pages > :last-child,
.pages > .page:target {
    display: block;
}
```

The rules applies in the following steps:

1. hide all pages
2. show both targeted page and the last page
3. if a page is targeted, hide the last page (`.page:target ~ .page:last-child`)

[(live example)](http://jsbin.com/emahek/2/edit#preview)

**Edit:** Apparently this is very similar to the accepted answer in [an older, previously mentioned, related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css).

Comment: Took a while to realise what was going on in your answer but now that I understand it, it seems like a very elegant solution

Comment: It is misleading to say that it is possible with CSS alone. In particular, this falls flat in its face when the "default" element you want to show is *not* the last child of its parent. How would you propose solving that problem with CSS alone then?

Comment: @BoltClock - Well, CSS and HTML alone.  I think the point is it does not require JavaScript, which is nice.

Comment: @BoltClock It would be possible with `:has()`, but no browser I know of implements this. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

It would look something like: `.pages > .page { display: none; } .pages:not(:has(.page:target)) > .page.default, .pages .page:target { display: block; }`

Comment: @rummik: The reason no browser implements :has() in CSS is because :has() has been excluded from CSS by the spec. The reason :has() isn't in CSS is because no one wants to take a stab at implementing it in CSS. If it ever gets implemented you'd probably still need JavaScript - but at least it'll involve less boilerplate JS then. One can hope...

Comment: @BoltClock `:has()` is still part of the CSS4 working draft, and it's under consideration by a number of development teams.  It's considered slow, which is part of why it hasn't been implemented.  `:not()` was in the same implementation boat a few years ago

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is that you have some javascript that checks to see if the hash is empty.  If so, it adds a class to the body tag called "noHash".  Then, you can use the fact that there is the noHash class available in your CSS rules.

```
if (window.location.hash.length <= 1) {
     document.body.className += " noHash";
}
```

Then, your CSS could be like this:

```
div {
  background: blue;
}
div:target, body.noHash div {
  background: red;
}
```

If there's any circumstance where a user might add a hash value after the fact, then you may have to watch for that to make sure the noHash class gets removed appropriately.

Note: you don't have to add the class name to the body tag.  You can add it to any parent object that covers all the objects you wish to affect.

Comment: Yeah you can't do this with CSS alone.

Comment: I was looking for a solution without javascript

Comment: @Rick de Vos - Good luck then.  From my read of the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo), your problem is that when there's no hash in the URL, all elements match no target which isn't what you want.  I don't think CSS3 does what you asked for.  There does not appear to be any way to match a class only when there is a hash in the URL that doesn't match that element.  Whatever CSS you try for that will match also when there is no hash in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great answer for this over at [default-target-with-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css)

It revolves around [this trick](http://jsfiddle.net/rED4c/) that seems to have problems in iOS. It's been fixed in Safari, so maybe it'll be in iOS 5?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`div:not(:target)`](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target) or [`div:target:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo)?

Comment: `:empty` has nothing to do with the topic actually. Also, I tried `:not(:target)` and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

With the :has selector gaining adoption, the following works (add a "default" class to the section to display when no target)

```css
section {
    display:none
}
section:target, :root:not(:has(:target)) section.default {
    display: block
}
```

As of Nov 2023 this works in Safari/Chrome, not yet Firefox but presumably won't be long