# CSS Tab Control - How do I show only the first div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay...I know there are already loads of Pure CSS Tab Controls out there...

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabPage1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabPage2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabPage3">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabPage1">
    <p>
        Hello World
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabPage2">
    <p>
        Goodbye World
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabPage3">
    <p>
        Another World, somewhere far, far away!
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.tabs > div {
    display: none;
}

.tabs > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

There's no styling for this example as I'm only concerned with the behavior.

You can try it here...http://jsfiddle.net/rcrdC/

1. How do I get it to display the first div until an anchor is clicked?
2. How do I get it to leave the displayed div...displayed, even when I change the anchor to something else (i.e. #tabPage4)...if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812170/1113766) , you can make the last one be display at the beginning with like this ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rcrdC/2/))

```
.tabs > div:target ~  div:last-child,
.tabs > div{
    display: none;
}
.tabs div:last-of-type,
.tabs > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Just move the first tabpage to be the last.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting challenge. Unfortunately, I don't believe the intended result can be achieved (purely) with CSS.

We can show the first `div` easily enough using:

```
div:first-of-type { display: block; }
```

But I don't know of a way to select our previously `:target`ed `div`s without using JavaScript.

Here I've set up some jQuery to apply class `.active` on any `div` with an id that equals that of a clicked anchor href. From there we can override `display: none;` on `div`s of that class with some simple CSS:

```
$('li a').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var active = $(this).attr('href');
        $(active).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

And here's the related CSS:

```
div:first-of-type, div:target { display: block; }
div { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

And a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fjKUw/1/

Answer (score 0):

showing the first tab on load should not be that hard. You can use the `:first-of-type` pseudo class. Something like this:

```
.tabs > div{
    display: none;
}
.tabs > div:first-of-type,
.tabs > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

The second question is a bit harder. The first tab will be shown again as soon as your target moves to an anchor outside the tabs. http://jsfiddle.net/rcrdC/4/ You need some way to preserve state. The 'real life' solution would be to add a few lines of javascript to achieve this, as suggested already by @StuartKershaw.

If you insist on going fully css, you could use a (hidden) radio button to preserve the state. It is a bit hacky (inputs are not meant for that) and you would have to change your markup a bit, but it should be feasible.

An example of what I mean can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/rcrdC/5/

Note that I placed some hidden radio buttons between the tabs. I replaced the links to the tabs by labels that reference those radio's. Then I use a combination of the `:checked` and the `+` selector to make things work. And the tab that is visible on load is the one with `checked` attribute.

Again, this is not the way I would recommend. You are adding to your markup, with the sole purpose of achieving a certain layout, which should be the task of your css. Also the stuff you need to add is far from semantically correct...