# Show select DIVs when hashed anchors are in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, toggle, anchor

I'd like to conditionally show a div when only a specific anchor link (myurl.com/#about) is displayed. I have .dynamic-content set to display: none in my css. #default-content shows, so I know I'm close, but I'm new to this level of scripting. What's the best way to get this to work? Thanks!

```js
(function($) {
  // Parse the URL parameter
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = location.href.split("#").slice(-1)[0];
    }

    return url;

  }
  // Give the parameter a variable name
  var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('#');

  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Check if the URL parameter is about
    if (dynamicContent == 'about') {
      $('#about').show();
    }
    // Check if the URL parameter is expertise
    else if (dynamicContent == 'expertise') {
      $('#expertise').show();
    }
    // Check if the URL parameter is contact
    else if (dynamicContent == 'contact') {
      $('#contact').show();
    }
    // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
    else {
      $('#default-content').show();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
  <div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
    This is the default content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 1 -->
  <div id="contact" class="dynamic-content">
    Contact content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 2 -->
  <div id="expertise" class="dynamic-content">
    Expertise content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
  <div id="about" class="dynamic-content">
    About content
  </div>
```

Comment: `window.location.hash.slice(1)` will get you the hash without the #

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use this method that Taplar suggested, or you can scrap this and use css only with the :target pseudo selector [See css tricks here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/)

Essentially you will hide your sections like you're already doing and then add a class with display:block like this

```
#contact:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Admittedly, showing default content is a little trickier. You could test that a value exists in the hash and show default content if it doesn't. I'll look into this and get back to you

**Edit:** Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867095/css-selector-when-target-empty)'s accepted answer using pseudo selectors

[Here's a link to that question](http://jsbin.com/emahek/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

You could maybe do something similar to this:

```css
/* based onhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867095/css-selector-when-target-empty */
.section-wrapper>.dynamic-content:target~#default-content,
.section-wrapper>.dynamic-content {
  display: none;
}

.dynamic-content>#default-content,
.dynamic-content>.dynamic-content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
    This is the default content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 1 -->
  <div id="contact" class="dynamic-content">
    Contact content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 2 -->
  <div id="expertise" class="dynamic-content">
    Expertise content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
  <div id="about" class="dynamic-content">
    About content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
</div>
```

Ran out of time, so didn't have a chance to test, but something like this should work

Comment: Please add a usage example :)

Comment: Thank you, I need to work with this a while to translate it

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your logic.  You can make a map of valid hashes to the selectors for the sections to show them.  Look the selector up, defaulting if it is not found, and show the section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contentByHash = {
    about: '#about'
    , expertise: '#expertise'
    , contact: '#contact'
  };
  var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  $(contentByHash[hash] || '#default-content').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I could only get #default-content to display