# Change Language in HTML using pure CSS without javascript

Tags: html, css

Good Day,

How can I change language in one HTML template only using pure CSS?

I tried this:

```css
body.en :lang(it) {
    display: none;
}
body.it :lang(en) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="it">
      <a href="" lang="it">it</a>
      <a href="" lang="en">en</a>

      <button onclick="document.body.className='en'">english</button>
      <button onclick="document.body.className='it'">italiano</button>
  <body>
</html>
```

But onclick is still a javascript if im not wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body.en [lang='it'] {
    display: none;
}
body.it [lang='en'] {
    display: none;
}
```

And you can toggle this by add default language class to body tag:

```html
<body class='en'></body>
```

And add js:

```js
document.querySelector('.lang-switch-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('en')
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('it')
})
```

Comment: how will you trigger that using button?

Comment: But, its still using javascript. I need to that using pure CSS.

Comment: You can toggle language with much ways, but they are all related with javascript. You can not change any attributes or class without javascript

Answer (score 1):

The question is about pure css. Of course one could achieve this with javascript. But there are several ways to do it with pure css.

You could use the `:target` selector in combination with ordinary links (instead of buttons) to choose the language like this:

```css
.main-content {
    display: none;
}
.main-content:target {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#it">italiano</a>
<a href="#en">english</a>

<div class="main-content" id="it">
...
</div>
<div class="main-content" id="en">
...
</div>
```

Another solution is using radio boxes or in combination with the `:checked` selector:

```css
.main-content {
    display: none;
}

#it:checked ~ .main-content[data-lang=it] {
    display: block;
}

#en:checked ~ .main-content[data-lang=en] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="it" />
<label for="it">italiano</label>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="en" />
<label for="en">english</label>

<div class="main-content" data-lang="it">
contenuto italiano
</div>
<div class="main-content" data-lang="en">
english content
</div>
```

But if your site has large content, you should consider to separate them in individual files.

Comment: For :target? how can we set default language during page load?

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812170/13720553 you could use the `:last-child` selector

Comment: Also, its not working on multiple divs

Comment: Instead the `:last-child` selector you could use the id of your default language which must be the last sibling of all languages. cf: https://jsfiddle.net/ahksvbd0/1/

Comment: but aside from divs. for example I also have <h1> English content</h1> and some other tags like <button>