# CSS3 default :target

Tags: css, state, target

I have the following code:

```
<style>
.temp {
    transition:all 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    /* Don't forget the vendor specific pre-fixes! */
}

/* .temp:first-child{opacity: 1;} */

.temp:target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size:40px;
}

#one:target {
  opacity: 1 ;
   font-size:40px
}
/*.tab:target ~ #one { opacity: 1;} */
</style>
<body>

<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<a href="#three">Three</a>
<a href="#four">Four</a>

<div class="buttons">
    <div class="temp" id="one"> Number One</div>  
    <div class="temp" id="two">Number Two</div>  
    <div class="temp" id="three">Number Three</div>  
    <div class="temp" id="four">Number Four</div>
</div>
```

**Task is to set the "default" state for div #one with css property {opacity:1;} only with CSS on page load.**

I also found this topic.
[Default :target with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css)

Also this code works very well.

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.location.hash="#"){
        document.location.hash="#one";
    }
}
```

But in case if I have more than one :target, not sure if it will work for both divs with :target state.

Is it possible? Thank you for attention and answers.