# displaying different div on navigation tab click, refreshing content, default select tab

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I am new to asp and css concepts, here I am stuck in a very basic problem

I have a navigation bar
`<li><a href = "#Div1" >Division 1</a></li>

<li><a href = "#Div2">Division 2</a></li>`

I have divisions as below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<div id = "TextBox">
    //a text box here which is common and should be displayed with both the sections below
</div>

<div id ="Div1" class= "section">
 // some button and text boxes here
</div>

<div id ="Div2" class= "section">
 // some button and text boxes here
</div>
</updatePanle>
```

css file:

```
.section { display:none }
.section:target { display: block }
```

The css file section definition helped in selecting the divisions properly but when the page loads there is only top TextBox div displayed.

So I need to display div1 content by default on page load, also when the textbox in TextBox div is populated by a value, the content refreshes and again there is no div1 or div2 content on page.

div are defined in an update panel

Thanks in advance in anticipation of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like only solution for this is using javascript.
[Rotora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318493/rotora) mentions a solution for this in a very similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css).

**HIS** solution (adjusted to your usecase) is

```
if (document.location.hash == "" || document.location.hash == "#")
    document.location.hash = "#Div1";
```

Comment: OK Thanks, It worked a bit but not completely. Art teh page load Div is diplayed but when i select Div2 from navigation bar then it displays a part of div1 first and then at the bottom div2.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      if (document.location.hash == "" || document.location.hash == "#")
        document.location.hash = "#Div1";
    </script>                                                                                                                                   css file     :                                                                                                                   .tab, .tab:target ~ #Div1{
  display: none;
}
#Div1, .tab:target {
  display: block;

  .tab, .tab:target ~ #Div2{
  display: none;
}
#Div2, .tab:target {
  display: block;
}

Comment: common text box is not visible on selection of Div2