# css3 only tabs preselect tab

Tags: html, css, tabs, pseudo-class

I am trying to create a CSS3 only tabs using :target pseudo-class

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs_wrapper" style="">
    <article class="tabs">
        <section id="tab1">
            <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
            <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="tab2">
            <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
            <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
        </section> 
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
article.tabs section:target h2
{
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color:#b8b63e;

}
article.tabs section:target{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

FIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/vchawla26/gxt708e7/

Everything is done.

Only facing an issue: that initially on load if no tab is clicked and target is empty, the tab is not highlighted :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default :target with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css)