# Is it possible to target "no target" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, fragment-identifier

Is there a css selector for "no fragment identifier present"? The opposite of `:target`.

The thing is, I'm making a document where different parts of it are visible depending on which fragment identifier you give it. Think of it as a sprite file, only for HTML.

So it looks like this

```html
<style>
 section {display:none}
 section:target {display:block}
</style>

<body>
 <section id="one">The first block (showing with #one)</section>
 <section id="two">The second block (showing with #two)</section>
 <section id="three">The third block (showing with #three)</section>
</body>
```

And the user sees the first section if it's displayed with `document.html#one` on the location bar, etc.

The idea is that the browser will cache the html page (since it is just static html) and no other content needs to be loaded when displaying another block of text, thus minimising server load.

But the file looks stupidly empty when you call it up without a fragment identifier, so I wonder if there's a way to make all of it visible in that case, without any hidden sections. CSS only, no JS or server side processing; otherwise it wouldn't be static HTML!

Edit:
Unlike the proposed duplicates, I would like to "simply" show the whole document when there's no fragment identifier, not just one element in particular.
In other words, the *default* (in the absence of any #) should be to show everything; only if there *is* an # should everything but the target be hidden.
The duplicates don't address this situation at all.

Comment: How do you minimise server load? The HTML file is served, and downloaded completely, even when you hide the section, they're still loaded and downloaded. So I don't quite understand how you think you are minimising.

Comment: @BramVanroy In this particular use case, I link to the file several times thoughout the website, with different fragment identifiers. So it will only be downloaded once (at least I hope so) and after the first time it will come from the user's cache.

Comment: See [my comment on one of the proposed duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css#comment46876088_3354279). Since the :target pseudo matches the target element, what do you expect to be matched by "the opposite of :target" when there *is no target element*?

Comment: @BoltClock I expected not much, but I was hoping for something really clever, something I hadn't thought of trying. Something like that over there ↓ in fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some extra markup and more verbose and specific CSS to write, to avoid javaScript. **Needs to be updated each time HTML structure is updated** .

```css
:target ~section {
  display:none;
}
#one:target ~.one,
#two:target ~.two,
#three:target ~.three  {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#one">One</a> 
  <a href="#two">Two</a>
  <a href="#three">Three</a>
  <a href="#">None of below targets</a>
</nav>
<!-- html anchor to allow use of :target ~ selectors -->
<a id="one"></a>
<a id="two"></a>
<a id="three"></a>
<!-- end anchor -->
<section class="one">The first block (showing with #one)</section>
<section class="two">The second block (showing with #two)</section>
<section class="three">The third block (showing with #three)</section>
```