# How do I not select a :target in CSS?

Tags: css

This is a simple CSS nav menu issue, I think. I'm using anchors to display/hide content with CSS.

CSS code:

```
div#content div {display: none;}

div#content div:target {display: block;}

div#content div#home:not(:target) {display: block;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/johrxwyn/2/

I'm trying to get it to show the home div whenever no targets are selected or the #home div is selected.

Any help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867095/css-selector-when-target-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector when :target empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867095/css-selector-when-target-empty)

Comment: Or maybe of [Is it possible to target “no target” in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38061792/1016716)