# CSS Display none/block - have specific DIV when page opens

Tags: css

I want to change page language without reload with pure CSS. I have some code that works as wanted when clicked - but on first page load no DIV is displayed.

I use simple code:

```
.expand {
  display: none;
}

.expand:target {
  display: block;
}
```

How do I need to code to show that one DIV is displayed on page load?

Here is my current jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yello/vhx92gbj/

ideally I would like to display the browser language upon first page load.

---

After lots of reading, this works for me the way I want it:

1.) Shows language A on first page load
2.) User can switch to language B without reload

https://jsfiddle.net/yello/68nbryr1/

I will the try the browser language detection shortly, my idea is:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

// output> en | de | fr etc

if($lang == 'de'){$deSite = 'default-tab';}
ELSE
{$enSite = 'default-tab';}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default :target with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css)

Comment: You can't do it by CSS, you need to script for that.

Comment: What are the requirements exactly? When should the .expand div be hidden? I mean, the .expand div should show when it's targeted, but also on initial page load when it's not targeted?

Comment: If you mean all .expand divs should show when there's no :target at all, this is a duplicate of [Is it possible to target “no target” in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38061792/1016716).

Comment: When page loads one of the DIV should show.
Aim: to offer different languages, currently no language is shown at all. I would prefer that i.e. English is shown, and the use can then click the flag to switch to German or French.
The Bhuwan posted gave me already some ideas and was certainly helpful. Needs a closer look tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. if you want english language show when page load. you just write below css.

```
.expand#english { display:block; }
```

Comment: english shows when page loads, but it's not hidden when other language is clicked.