# Highlighting active tab with single page navigation

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I really hope I'm not repeating an old question - I'm new to selectors so my terminology might be lacking.

I'm working on a tabbed single-page webpage based around this [Default :target with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354279/default-target-with-css/29344677#29344677) solution. I would like the current tab to have its link highlighted or altered in some way, to indicate the current location.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="tabnav">
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<a id="tab1"></a>
<a id="tab2"></a>

<div class="tab tab1 default-tab">This is text you should see as you load the page</div>
<div class="tab tab2">This is text that will appear after you click on tab 2</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tab {
    display:none
}
.default-tab {
    display:block
}

:target ~ .default-tab {display:none}

#tab1:target ~ .tab1,
#tab2:target ~ .tab2 {
    display: block
}

ul#tabnav a:hover { 
    background: red;
}

ul#tabnav a:target{
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: black;
}
```

It seems like my last element (a:target) doesn't do anything, even though clicking on tabs does bring me to new anchors and change the displayed content. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`:target` is the selector for the element on the page that has the `id` or `name` of the anchor name in the URL. So `ul#tabnav a:target` won't match anything, but if you change the selector to `a:target`, it will style the 2 links you have in the middle of the page, `<a id="tab1"></a><a id="tab2"></a>`

To style the "active" link in your navigation you'll need to use javascript to add a class on click, then style that class.

```js
var $links = $('#tabnav a');
$links.on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $links.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.tab {display:none}
.default-tab {display:block}

:target ~ .default-tab {display:none}

#tab1:target ~ .tab1,
#tab2:target ~ .tab2 {
  display: block
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabnav">
        <li><a href="#tab1" class="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="tab1"></a>
    <a id="tab2"></a>

    <div class="tab tab1 default-tab">
        This is text you should see as you load the page
    </div>
    <div class="tab tab2">
        This is text that will appear after you click on tab 2
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, 
Thank you for your reply. That information about ids & :target was news to me! I've been trying to use minimal jquery/javascript in this work (perhaps foolishly). I suspect a script-free solution might be possible (e.g. https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/ example 6), but the lack of a default "tab" is troublesome.

Comment: @K.D.Mortimer yeah it's possible, but not with your markup. I was working with the markup you provided. All of those solutions are hacky - I don't see the point when you can write a couple of lines of javascript that make it clean. This stuff is controlling the state of the page - CSS doesn't do that well, or at all really. CSS is just for design. Javascript is the standard for manipulating page state, and CSS pairs with it to reflect the design of the page's state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap tabs it will solve you problem and works fine.

Please check the demo [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h)

Hope this will solve you problem.

Happy Coding :)